# Is there something wrong with my HTML code for a button?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a button that's supposed to open up some text when it's clicked, and close the text when it's clicked again. Here's the code for it:

```
<button id = "hello" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = buttonScript">
    wow look a button
</button>
<p id = "demo">

</p>
</body>
<script>
    var buttonScript;
    if (document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML === "Hello there! Click the button again to close it."){
        buttonScript = " ";
    }
    else {
        buttonScript = "Hello there! Click the button again to close it.";
    }
</script>
```

It works when you click it once, but the text doesn't go away when it's clicked again. I'm not sure why this is happening, could someone please tell me where I made my noob mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is every time your button gets clicked, it needs to do that evaluation. You're only doing it that evaluation once when the page loads. Your click event doesn't have any logic, it's just a statement - *Set the `<p>` to have whatever buttonScript curently is* - but buttonScript is never changing.

It's alot easier to work with functions for this kind of thing. In this function we have the line : `el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.trim() === buttonScript ? "" : buttonScript` which says *IF the innerHTML  of the element (after any extra spaces were removed) == buttonScript THEN set it to empty OTHERWISE set it to buttonScript*

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('hello').addEventListener('click', doTheThing);
  }

  function doTheThing(e) {
    var buttonScript = "Hello there! Click the button again to close it."
    let el = document.getElementById('demo');
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.trim() === buttonScript ? "" : buttonScript
  }
```

```css
button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="hello" type="button">
    wow look a button
</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot :)
I notice that you used `let` for variable declaration. Should I use that instead of `var` in local scopes?

Comment: `let` and `const` are used more now since they got introduced to JS recently. They both have different applications so make sure you look up the references on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Comment: Okay. I've found that on some editors, I get an error when I use `let` for global variables. I believe that would just be a problem with the editor?

And a totally unrelated question - is there any way I can center the button in CSS without having to put it in a `div`?

Comment: For this kind of thing `var` is fine, but the future is all `let` and `const` so it's good to study up.  I added in the CSS to show how to center the button. If this solved your question, please mark as the answer (click the checkmark on the left). Cheers

Comment: Never ever use `on*` handlers besides when creating brand new in-memory Elements. use the proper `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - excellent points. OP is obviously at early stage of learning, didn't want to throw too much change at once, but it's best to do it right from the beginning. Updated

Comment: You 're not coding for the future - but for the present. you do not use syntax that is not compatible with current UAs or write code future standards, unless you like to be fired by your boss because he hates upgrades and your code doesn't work on his laptop!

Comment: Yes, USE let or const. var is deprecated and will stop working some day, PLUS it doesn't have block level scoping. https://hackernoon.com/why-you-shouldnt-use-var-anymore-f109a58b9b70

Comment: It's a balancing act writing answers. Because you need to understand the needs of the OP, the scope of their understanding, and your own competence at writing smart answers that will both inform and educate people without being patronising. It's difficult because some people might be learning from material that was written a decade ago, and the fast pace of JS development does leave many people in the wind. "Never" is the wrong word if you don't explain _why_.

Answer (score -1):

Modern JS gives many tools with which to work, so I'll explain some of them.

1. Cache your elements outside of the function. I favour [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) because these methods allow us to use CSS properties that aren't really available with other nodelists.
2. Modern JS doesn't really use inline JS any more. We pick up the elements and add an [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to them instead.
3. Elements have a [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) method that allows us to toggle between one class state an another as long as you have that set up in your CSS.

```js
// Cache the elements
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const div = document.querySelector('#demo');

const buttonScript = 'Hello there! Click the button again to close it.'

// Add the text to your div
div.textContent = buttonScript;

// Add the click listener to the button
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick() {

  // Toggle the hidden class on and off
  // when you click the button
  div.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

```css
button { margin: 0 auto; display: block; }
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<button>wow look a button</button>
<p class="hidden" id="demo"></p>
```